# wireless hard blocked on hp pavilion sleek-book 15

Tags: 16.04, wireless, hp-pavilion

My network adapter was working fine when I was on a dual boot, but after I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and removed win10 the wireless did not work. I tried rfkill:

soft blocked no
hard blocked yes
I press fn+f12; it changes the soft block only from yes to no but the hard block stays yes. I formatted my PC to win10 again it works fine but when I try to use any Linux distro the WiFi does not work.

Here is the output of `sudo rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Here is the output of `sudo lspci -nnk`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex [1022:1410]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex [103c:193b]
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7400G] [1002:9994]
    DeviceName: AMD Radeon HD 7400G
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Trinity [Radeon HD 7400G] [103c:193b]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller [1002:9902]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Trinity HDMI Audio Controller [103c:193b]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port [1022:1414]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:10.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller [1022:7812] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH USB XHCI Controller [103c:193b]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7804]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [103c:193b]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:12.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7807] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH USB OHCI Controller [103c:193b]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
00:12.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7808] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH USB EHCI Controller [103c:193b]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:13.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7807] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH USB OHCI Controller [103c:193b]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
00:13.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7808] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH USB EHCI Controller [103c:193b]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:780b] (rev 14)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH SMBus Controller [103c:193b]
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller [1022:780d] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH Azalia Controller [103c:193b]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:780e] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH LPC Bridge [103c:193b]
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge [1022:780f] (rev 40)
00:15.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0) [1022:43a0]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:15.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1) [1022:43a1]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0 [1022:1400]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1 [1022:1401]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2 [1022:1402]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3 [1022:1403]
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4 [1022:1404]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5 [1022:1405]
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
02:00.1 Bluetooth [0d11]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth [1814:3298]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIE CardReader
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [103c:193b]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:193b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: this is the out put of `rfkill` and `lspci -nnk` in this[link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23560603/)

Comment: May we also see a paste of: `lsmod` ? Thanks.

Comment: lsmod https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rFX97ct5CW/

Answer (score 1):

In your lsmod paste, we see that two modules are loaded that are supposed to respond to the Fn+F12 key presses to turn on and off the wireless radio. The modules in question are hp-wireless and hp-wmi. We wonder if *both* are required or if they conflict.

Let’s try removing one to see if the Fn+F12 combination now works as expected. From the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r hp-wireless
```

Now try Fn+F12. Is there any improvement? If not, reload it and try the other:

```
sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi
sudo modprobe hp-wireless
```

Now try Fn+F12. Is there any improvement? Whichever works, if either, we can make permanent in an edit to this answer.

Comment: it didn't work .you should know that this wificard is  wifi bleutooth combo the bleutooth part is not recognized at all